# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x48) error when trying to play audio

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I am trying to play an audio file when a button is pressed in Xcode. I have gotten this to work in a previous project(that was in an earlier version of Xcode), however now when I try to do it I get the error on the line `player.play()`. I have my file saved in the main bundle.

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x48)

```
func playExpression(_ word: String){

    //sets up the audio player for the word
    var player:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    do {
        //gets the audio file and links it to the player.
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: word, ofType: "mp3")
        try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!) as URL)
    }
    catch {
        /*ERROR*/
    }

    //plays the  audio clip
    player.play()
    print("audio played")
    sleep(UInt32(1)) //gives the audio clip time to play
}

@IBAction func speakerPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        playExpression("testaudio")
    }
```

UPDATE: The audio file I was trying to play was corrupted, causing it to crash. Once I changed the file, it did play.

Comment: Never use `sleep` (or equivalent) on the main queue.

Comment: What line causes the crash?

Comment: Have you checked no error thrown in your do-catch block? What do you get in the debug console, When you replace `/*ERROR*/` with `print(error)` ?

Comment: Why `NSURL` with cast to `URL`? There is `url(forResource:withExtension:)`. If this code causes a crash then the file is not in the bundle or the file name is misspelled.

Comment: The line that caused the error is `player.play()`

Comment: let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: word, ofType: "mp3") You need "word" the "" are missing arund word